# Can't start chrome, permission denied

Tags: permissions, google-chrome

Here's what I'm getting:

```
$ google-chrome
[5934:5934:0812/222947:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(394)] readlink failed: Permission denied
[5934:5934:0812/222947:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(240)] readlink(/home/julian/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied
[5934:5934:0812/222947:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(240)] readlink(/home/julian/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied
[5934:5934:0812/222947:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(264)] Failed to create /home/julian/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock: Permission denied
[5934:5934:0812/222947:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(394)] readlink failed: Permission denied
[5934:5934:0812/222947:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(240)] readlink(/home/julian/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied
[5934:5934:0812/222947:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1209)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
[5934:5965:0812/222947:ERROR:nss_util.cc(737)] Error initializing NSS with a persistent database (sql:/home/starkers/.pki/nssdb): NSS error code: -8187
```

This is my fault as I've fiddled with my permissions. However I would like to know how to get chrome working again.

Is there some kind of command to reset permissions? I confess I've been a bit of a cowboy but I don't want to have to reinstall :(

Answer (score 3):

Issue this command:

```
sudo chown -R julian:julian ~/.config
```

To restore the whole account's ownership:

```
sudo chown -R julian:julian ~
```